# 500 internal error for Ajax and jQuery .Load() functions, visiting url directly works fine. 1and1 Server

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

So I am using a jQuery .load() call to implement endless pagination in a CakePHP web app.

Here is the Javascript code:

```
$("#post_container").append('<div class="batch row" style="display:none;"></div>'); //append a container to hold ajax content
        var url = $("a#next").attr("href"); //extract the URL from the "next" link
        $(".paging").remove(); // remove the old pagination links because new ones will be loaded via ajax
        if(url === undefined)
        {
            $("#ajax_pagination_text").html("<strong>Turtles all the way down. No more posts :(</strong>");
        }

        $("div.batch").load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "error") {
              var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
              alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            }
            else {
                $(this).attr("class","loaded row"); //change the class name so it will not be confused with the next batch
                $(".paging").hide(); //hide the new paging links
                $(this).fadeIn();

            }
        });
```

The important part here is the $.load() which tries to load a url (http://www.MYWEBSITE.com/posts/index/page:2). When jQuery makes the request the server returns a 500 internal server error Same thing if I use jQuery.ajax(url);. If I go to that url directly it loads, no problem.

The ajax call works fine on my local development server as well. So this must be something with the setup on my host 1and1. What's going on here? I've already had to deal with a few 500 server errors with this host.

I've changed my .htaccess files as follows to fix previous 500 errors:

.htaccess in CakePHP root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
   SetEnv PHP_VER

   RewriteEngine ON
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess in CakePHP app/:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   AddType x-mapp-php5 .php


    RewriteEngine ON
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

.htaccess in CakePHP app/webroot/:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
   AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

    RewriteEngine ON
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

any help or insight is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this was a problem in the way I was changing which view was rendered by Cake depending on whether the call was AJAX or not.

Originally I had this, to change the view that is rendered:

```
if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {  
   $this->render('/posts/ajax_paging');  // Special view for ajax pagination
}
```

Which worked flawlessly on my local development server. But once uploaded this was having problems. The server said it couldn't find the view.

Changing it to the following fixed the issue:

```
if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {  
  $this->render('ajax_paging');  // Render a special view for ajax pagination
}
```

I'm guessing it had to do with the fact that the actual folder "Posts" has a capitol P and my windows server is not case sensitive so "/posts" resolved to "/Posts" but once I put it on the linux servers at 1and1 the case became an issue.. Also after reading the CakePHP documentation I realized I didn't even need the directory since the view was from the same controller. Hence the resulting code.

Answer (score 1):

Install Wireshark and determine the difference between the request your browser makes when you navigate to the page versus when you request it using AJAX.

http://www.wireshark.org/

Only then will you have a better idea of what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, the difference is that one is an AJAX request while the other is a vanilla GET. This led me to looking at my controller code and I remembered I have a check that changes which Layout is used to render the request when the request is AJAX. commenting this out fixes the Ajax request and it works. Though not properly as I have a different layout for reason. Updating my question after I play around with this a bit more.

Comment: As far as the HTTP protocol is concerned there's no difference between an AJAX request and a "vanilla" request. The differences lie strictly with how the browser processes the information. With that in mind you should be able to look at the differences in the request and determine the issue or at least adjust whatever settings are necessary to get the AJAX request to mimic your vanilla get so you don't trigger whatever server error is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use $post instead?.
When my parameter is greater than one, I use $.post or get, $.ajax for just one parameter.